# How to simulate driving a route in real device

Tags: android, location

I have a locations based app and I want to test it without real moving.
I know I can provide a kml file of points but I don't want to use emulator, but real device.
could you tell me what is the best way to simulate driving a route on the device?

**I emphasize that I need to simulate an entire route rather than a single point.**


thank you for giving your time

Answer (score 43):

I'm using mock locations in the development of my app.  The following two apps have proved reliable in mocking locations (static location & routes) thus far:

**Lockito**

- I use Lockito to create routes that are *snapped to roads*.  Routes are created within Lockito.  After a route has been created, Lockito can then playback the route as a series of mock locations that affect other apps reading GPS location.
- Speed control is available for playing back routes.
- Routes can be saved and loaded to be played back another time.
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.dvilleneuve.lockito

**Teleport**

- I use Teleport to create routes from *.KML files*. Teleport accepts .KML files in "TrackMatch format".
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shankarlabs.teleport

**How I Use Lockito and Teleport in Conjunction with my App**

I would have either Lockito or Teleport ^ mocking my device's location while my app is running.  That is, I would have at lesat 2 apps "running" on my device when mocking locations - my app, and either Lockito or Teleport.

^ I don't use both Lockito and Teleport at the same time for fear of unintended consequences.

---

Digression:

Ways I create .KML files:

1) http://www.mapmash.in/kmlpolyline.html

2) Google Earth

Comment: Teleport is not available anymore (probably was removed from Play Store after Pokemon Go hype), use Lockito to record and play back routes

Answer (score 5):

I needed to test driving journeys with my app, that had inaccuracies and were actually real life scenarios (e.g. tunnels, city driving, intermittent GPS signal) I did this using two apps, one mentioned by davidleejy, and going out for a drive once to gather the data:

**[GPS Logger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mendhak.gpslogger&hl=en_GB)** - To record the initial journey on the road as a .kml or .gpx

**[Lockito](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.dvilleneuve.lockito&hl=en_GB)** -  To play back the journey.

Answer (score -1):

The android emulator for Visual Studio that runs with Hyper-visor has a GPS option to follow road and go speed limit (or to go 400 mph, walk, and some other options).  However, the latest windows update to fall creator's update winver 1709 seems to have broken the launching of the emulator.  Switching to the Android studio emulator with HAXM does not have the "follow road" and "go speed limit" options.

Comment: The question stated using real device, not emulator.