# Testing Activity Recognition

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

I've implemented the Activity Recognition API with Google Play Services in order to detect driving, and I would like to debug it on Android Studio.
There is a way to do it without really driving?

Comment: Maybe you can look to the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258922/how-to-simulate-driving-a-route-in-real-device) for some possibilities? Not entirely sure how activity recognition determines the activity, but I have to imagine it utilizes the device gps/position somehow, so if you simulate movement, it might work.

Comment: @Andy same comment given below to an answer: how about if you initiate a Close Vote for Duplicate question and we back you up with it?