# How to simulate driving a route with all details

Tags: android, location

I have a location-based app and I want to test it without really moving.
I know I can provide a kml file of points but I don't want to use an emulator, but a real device.

could you tell me what is the best way to simulate driving a route on the device? 
I emphasize that I need to simulate an entire route with each detail like the exact speed at each point... etc

thank you for giving your time

Comment: use fake gps apps.They provide joystick control so you can move around

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate driving a route in real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258922/how-to-simulate-driving-a-route-in-real-device)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mock Location](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.gavrikov.mocklocations&hl=en_IN) to perform real-time tracking just put source and destination in the `mock location app`.
For using `mock location app` you have to enable the **Allow mock location** from developer option. Check [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/fake-android-location/).